# python django newline not working with replace in richtextfield

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, django-models

***models.py***

```
description = RichTextField(blank=True, null=True)
```

***admin.py***

```
description = "*text1/*text2/*text3"




desired_output = "*text1
                  *text2
                  *text3"
```

#I Tried to do with replace but it dont work  -  description.replace("/", "\n")

#replace dont work to get newline in RichTextField Any Solutions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `\n` failed to produce a new line in the richtextfield.  Replacing `\n` with html style tag for line break `<br>` solved the problem.

```
description = "*text1/*text2/*text3"

desired_description = re.sub(r"/", "<br>", description)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).